# In php how to replace a '/' and find in between numbers

Tags: php

In php how to replace  a '/'  and  find in between numbers

Example:

```
$a = 30/36;

// i need to get  $a  value  is 30,31,32,33,34,35,36  using php
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print_r(range(...explode('/', '30/36')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple google search would give you the answer. ..

```
$a = '1/2/3/4/5';
$res = str_replace('/', ',', $a);

echo $res;
```

**EDIT:**  As per @NigelRen request! Took part from @u_mulder (i think acceptable answer) to complete my answer!

```
$a = '30/36';
$res = str_replace('/', ',', $a);

$range = range(...explode(',', '30,36'));
$range = implode(',', $range);
echo $range;
```

Comment: How would this work with `30,36` to give `30,31,32,33,34,35,36`?

Comment: He is not asking for that. . For me it just looks like example not need.

Comment: So you think that using `'1/2/3/4/5'` is close to what they are asking for?

Comment: The example is very clear - the problem I have with it is that they have shown no effort in solving this themselves before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$a = '30/36';
$explode=(explode("/",$a));
print_r($explode);
$range=(range($explode[0],$explode[1]))  ;
echo implode(",",$range);
```